# Identifying number of iframes in a page using Selenium with java?

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, frame

Is there any method to identify the following in Selenium?

```
Number of iframes in a page
Attributes/Details of the current iframe
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! along with the size() method, used switchTo() method to navigate to the frame. Initially I had difficulty in identifying the current frame using java code(I wonder if there is one!). Through the help of Inspect element in chrome, identified the frame name and now I'm able to identify the elements in that frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")).size();
```

For acquiring details of current frame I propose you switch to it using a `WebElement` object and `switchTo`, and then get attributes like you normally do, with `getAttribute`

**UPD**

In fact, yes, first will give the amount of iframes in current context. If you don't want to do it recursively, but want a quick and working (dirty) solution - just get the page source and find all inclusions of `"<iframe"` string

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have stated, you can identify the number of frames **in the currently focused context** using:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")).size();
```

However this will not identify any frames that are children of another frame. To do so, you will need to switch to that parent frame first.

To retrieve attributes such as name or id for the currently focused frame you can use JavascriptExecutor like so:

```
String currentFrameName = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.frameElement.name");
```

Comment: That's the best answer here I believe.

Comment: I'm receiving the following error when I use the above code:

        "Cannot read property 'name' of null"

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you at the top level context of the page when you are trying to execute "return window.frameElement.name"? "window.frameElement" will return null if you are focusing the top level content of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example how you can approach it:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe");

// find all your iframes
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));
        // print your number of frames
        System.out.println(iframes.size());

        // you can reach each frame on your site
        for (WebElement iframe : iframes) {

            // switch to every frame
            driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

            // now within the frame you can navigate like you are used to
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).getText());
        }
```